# MockEndpoints with CamelSpringRunner & JavaConfig

Tags: spring, testing, apache-camel

This works for me using deprecated CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader, which I think should not be used, because it duplicates the work of CamelTestContextBootstrapper. If I omit CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader, the test fails to autowire CamelContext (bean not found, if I comment CamelContext, input is null) so injection does not work. But this is the suggested way to implement testing (e.g. CamelSpringRunnerPlainTest).
My camel version is 2.21.2. CamelBootSpringRunner would also work, but I don't want to run the test with Spring Boot without need. Also I would not want to extend a class like SpringTestSupport.

```
    @RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@MockEndpoints
@DirtiesContext(
        classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class,
    classes = MyTest.TestConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:in")
    private ProducerTemplate input;
...
@Configuration
static class TestConfig extends CamelConfiguration {
...
```

Comment: Have you tried with a newer Camel version

Comment: I tried with 2.23.1. It exposes the same behavior. Also I'm stuck with 2.21 because from 2.22 Camel goes with spring 5, which in turn goes with java ee 7 interfaces, but I need to run the application on IBM WebSphere 8.5, which only supports java ee 6...